# WebView2.CoreWevView2 is missing ServerCertificateErrorDetected event handler

Tags: wpf, webview2

I am developing a WPF application in .NET 4.8. I have installed the WebView2 through NuGet package

`<package id="Microsoft.Web.WebView2" version="1.0.1210.39" targetFramework="net48" />`

I am trying to handle the server certificate error. But when I try to access this event handler it seems the CoreWebView2 doesn't recognize it.

[image]

I tried to create a simple project in WPF and installed the WebView2 using NuGet package with the exact version but still, I can't see this event handler there. I have also realized that there are some more events that are missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`CoreWebView2.ServerCertificateErrorDetected` is only available in prerelease nuget packages 1.0.1222 and more recent. See the [`CoreWebView2.ServerCertificateErrorDetected` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.servercertificateerrordetected?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1248-prerelease) which lists the applicable versions at the bottom.

You can change your webview2 nuget package to the latest prerelease version to try this API.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply. I can't use the prerelease version at the moment. Can you please suggest me how can achieve similar functionality with WebView2 version: 1.0.1210.39?

Comment: Its not available in that version. If you cannot use prerelease versions you can wait for that API to become available in a release package.